# How to install the OS when testing a bare-metal recovery?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, backup, data-recovery

I run a home server on Ubuntu 18.04. It boots from a M2 internal drive (`/dev/sda1`) and basically

- mounts another drive (`/dev/sdc1`)
- mounts an LVM partition (`/dev/mapper/data-data`)
- starts docker which in turn runs a set of containers

I would like to test a disaster scenario where the M2 (boot) drive fails. My backup is stored on `/dev/sdc1` (and also remotely, which is the same type of testing).

In order to perform the test I would like to

- remove the M2 drive (this is to simulate its failure, and also protect from a mistake which would damage it)
- plug in an external USB drive (USB drive 1)
- boot from a Ubuntu ISO (flashed on USB drive 2)
- install Ubuntu on the external drive (= on USB drive 1, and then remove and forget USB drive 2)
- install docker and other utilities, recover the backup, start the containers etc. ← that part is simpler as I (hopefully) understand how to orchestrate the activities.

My main concern (there may be others I am not aware of) is **whether the external USB drive will be recognized as a "proper" drive to install the system**. Are there limitation on the kind of connectivity for an installation?

The alternative is to borrow an M2 drive and swap the existing one with the "recovery" one but I would prefer to do the testing on the USB one, which I already have.

Additionally - are there any possible problems with the testing process above? (especially the part from "disaster" to having a shell prompt and start the last point -- I am sure I will discover a lot of problems in the last one but I will be able to handle them fine, the booting process which I am not that acquired with is the one I do not feel comfortable with)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to install the system from ISO image which resides on USB-drive? You must then install grub onto USB-drive and set the grub to boot from ISO image. If this is what you are asking, I can provide my setup as an example.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu onto a USB drive. If you are not using USB 3.0 hardware and port, then it may be noticeably slow.

Comment: @wk. this is probably not what I had in mind (I updated my question to clarify the drives) but I would be very much interested in your setup as it is a good and simpler alternative. If you would mind posting it as an answer that would be great.

Comment: You could boot from a LiveUSB, and use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to test your recovery process without even needing to remove the (unmounted) boot drive.

Comment: @user535733: this is also something I was considering, instead of installing (I was just wondering about the ability to flash the Ubuntu ISO on an external disk vs a USB drive - though that should make no difference). I would still remove the M2 drive, I have made in my years in IT some fenomenal  "oh shit" errors and I prefer to err on the safe side :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample `grub` menu entry to **run live** Ubuntu ISO-image:

```
menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing 18.04.3" {
  loopback loop /boot/images/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   (loop)/casper/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=/boot/images/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso   file=(loop)/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    initrd  (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

Sample for **installing** Ubuntu from mini-ISO:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu mini 18.04 64bit cli expert" {
 loopback loop /boot/images/ubuntu__18.04__mini64.iso
 linux (loop)/linux iso-scan/filename=/boot/images/ubuntu__18.04__mini64.iso tasks=standard pkgsel/language-pack-patterns= pkgsel/install-language-support=false priority=low --
 initrd (loop)/initrd.gz
}
```

And [howto install grub onto USB](https://current.workingdirectory.net/posts/2009/grub-on-usb/)